# Visual Studio C++ executes cmd.exe instead of my program

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010

My main() code is extremely simple. It is literally just printing out "Whatevs". It is part of a larger project with lots of CPP and H files, but I just need my main() to actually do something first :/ When I run it, it runs C:/windows/system32/cmd.exe. What it should be running is MyProgram.exe. And all it says is "Press any key to continue" like my program never ran- it doesn't print out what I said. What internal problem in Visual Studio C++ would cause such an error?

My main():

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "EmployeeRecord.h"
#include "CustomerList.h"
#include "Store.h"
int main(void)
{
    cout<<"Whatevs";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I have other source files, but I am guessing they are not the problem

Comment: Show us the code. There may be a lot of reasons this happen before "A Visual Studio internal problem"..

Comment: Unfortunately my favorite C++ FAQ item about how to post a question about code that doesn't work, has gone missing in the migration of the FAQ to ISO CPP. But essentially, do provide the code, we're not telepaths! And also all else that can possibly be relevant, such as your Visual Studio project settings. (Note that the project file is a simple text file).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, [Here you go](https://web.archive.org/web/20121519492500/http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/posting-code.html)

Comment: @JBL, the code has been posted

Comment: The reason `cmd.exe` is running is that that's what the system() function does.  So Visual Studio is running your program, and your program is running `cmd.exe` (and telling it to execute the "pause" command).

Answer (score 2):

> *"What internal problem in Visual Studio C++ would cause such an error?"*

There is no *internal problem with Visual Studio*. You simply miss to get the output buffer flushed, that's why you don't see your output appearing.

Write either

```
cout << "Whatevs";
cout.flush();
```

or

```
cout << "Whatevs" << endl; // endl flushes implicitely
```

to see the output appearing in the terminal.